# Uknown connector type

Tags: connector

I'm looking for some information for the type of the connector this drone is using.

My nephew lost his charging cable for it and he can't reachage it anymore.

Can someone provide me with information if this connector has a specific name that I can look for or it's some proprietary connector that can't be found.

Below is a close up image on the connector in question and here is the link to the drone itself: https://uae.souq.com/ae-en/taiyo-water-drone-29717429/i/

Any info will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: That look like standard cheap drones USB charger connector such as https://www.amazon.com/Syma-X5C-USB-Charging-Cable/dp/B00P2XIEAI

Comment: Thanks for the info, if I can't find something similar I will figure some DIY solution.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Mating male to male? Very contemporary of you :)

Comment: It looks similar to [JST RCY](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1-pair-100mm-150mm-200mm-10cm-15cm-JST-Connector-Male-Plug-Female-Connect-Cable-Wire-for/32802386524.html) connector, but not quite the same. You can buy a mating pair and replace both plug and socket.

Comment: It depends what the charger side port looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It rather looks like "SYMA-X5C-X5S-X5SC-X5SW-X5HW-X5A-1-X5HC-RC-[Quadcopter-Lithium-Battery-Connectors-Battery-Charging](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/SYMA-X5C-X5S-X5SC-X5SW-X5HW-X5A-1-X5HC-RC-Quadcopter-Lithium-Battery-Connectors-Battery-Charging/32869566718.html)" connector,

[image]

You need the red end, whichever the name is. JST connectors do not have the split/notch.